# Get the index of Voronoi sites corresponding to input vertices

Tags: cgal

I am using the [code](https://github.com/sloriot/cgal-voronoi-cropping) found on github, in order to generate a Voronoi diagram using a set of input vertices and a rectangle.

I want to implement manually the weighted CVT algorithm. The problem is that when the Voronoi diagram is created, the order of vertices/sites is not the same as the input vertices. The result is actually a Half-edge data structure. So when I use the following code:

```
for (VD::Face_iterator fit = vd.faces_begin(),
  fit_end = vd.faces_end();
  fit != fit_end; ++fit)
  {
      std::cout << fit->dual()->point() << std::endl;

 }
```

The resulting vertices printed are in a different order than the input vertices.
Is there a way to somehow get the new indices now faster. The only way I thought I could do this is to compare distances, but this will be really slow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Triangulation_vertex_base_wih_info_2](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/classCGAL_1_1Triangulation__vertex__base__with__info__2.html) in order to store the index in the vertices.